# C++ with MSVC: Variadic ctor in derived class gets argument list wrong when calling base class ctor. Compiler bug or user error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-templates

While trying to port code to Windows, MSVC threw a compiler error for code which compiles fine on gcc or clang. I tried to create a somewhat minimal reproducible example below. The idea is to group errors by type, and to allow the `fmt` syntax in the error construction. The base class normally inherits from `std::exception`, but to make the example smaller, I removed that, and also the inclusion of `fmt` here. The problem seems to be the variadic ctor in the derived class.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

/* to get meaningful error messages, exception classes can define a type and
 * inherit from ErrorWithType, which concatenates the type and the passed in
 * error message for what() output */
class ErrorWithType
{
protected:
    std::string m_error;
    
    std::string errorMsg( std::string_view typeStr, std::string error ){
        return std::string{ typeStr } + ": " + error;
    }
    
public:
    /* ctor to be called when no further arguments are provided */
    ErrorWithType(std::string_view typeStr, std::string error) :
        m_error { errorMsg( typeStr, std::move(error) ) }
    {}

    /* ctor for chaining to fmt::format, left here for illustrative purposes,
     * but compiler error occurs elsewhere */
    // template<typename ... Args>
    // ErrorWithType(std::string_view typeStr, std::string fmtStr, Args&& ... args) :
    //  m_error { errorMsg( typeStr, fmt::format(
    //      std::move(fmtStr),
    //      std::forward<Args>(args) ...
    //  ) ) }
    // {}
    
    const char* what() const noexcept {
        return m_error.c_str();
    }
};


/* the error types are created with this macro,
 * which just contains a static string_view member describing the type,
 * and a variadic ctor, which chains to either of the base class ctors. */
#define ERROR_WITH_TYPE(CLASS_NAME, TYPE_STRING) \
class CLASS_NAME : public ErrorWithType { \
private: static constexpr std::string_view m_type { TYPE_STRING }; \
public: \
    template<typename ... Args> \
    CLASS_NAME(Args&& ... args) : \
        ErrorWithType(m_type, std::forward<Args>(args)...) \
    {} \
};

/* the macro allows creating error types succinctly: */
ERROR_WITH_TYPE(RuntimeError, "Runtime error")
ERROR_WITH_TYPE(LogicError, "Logic error")

void throwError(){
    /* and the next line causes the error */
    throw LogicError("This is a logic error.");
}
```

The above code compiles fine on [clang/gcc (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:58,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:58,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:58,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:58),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0A/*+to+get+meaningful+error+messages,+exception+classes+can+define+a+type+and%0A+*+inherit+from+ErrorWithType,+which+concatenates+the+type+and+the+passed+in%0A+*+error+message+for+what()+output+*/%0Aclass+ErrorWithType%0A%7B%0Aprotected:%0A%09std::string+m_error%3B%0A%09%0A%09std::string+errorMsg(+std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+error+)%7B%0A%09%09return+std::string%7B+typeStr+%7D+%2B+%22:+%22+%2B+error%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0Apublic:%0A%09/*+ctor+to+be+called+when+no+further+arguments+are+provided+*/%0A%09ErrorWithType(std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+error)+:%0A%09%09m_error+%7B+errorMsg(+typeStr,+std::move(error)+)+%7D%0A%09%7B%7D%0A%0A%09/*+ctor+for+chaining+to+fmt::format,+left+here+for+illustrative+purposes,%0A%09+*+but+compiler+error+occurs+elsewhere+*/%0A%09//+template%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E%0A%09//+ErrorWithType(std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+fmtStr,+Args%26%26+...+args)+:%0A%09//+%09m_error+%7B+errorMsg(+typeStr,+fmt::format(%0A%09//+%09%09std::move(fmtStr),%0A%09//+%09%09std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)+...%0A%09//+%09)+)+%7D%0A%09//+%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09const+char*+what()+const+noexcept+%7B%0A%09%09return+m_error.c_str()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0A/*+the+error+types+are+created+with+this+macro,%0A+*+which+just+contains+a+static+string_view+member+describing+the+type,%0A+*+and+a+variadic+ctor,+which+chains+to+either+of+the+base+class+ctors.+*/%0A%23define+ERROR_WITH_TYPE(CLASS_NAME,+TYPE_STRING)+%5C%0Aclass+CLASS_NAME+:+public+ErrorWithType+%7B+%5C%0Aprivate:+static+constexpr+std::string_view+m_type+%7B+TYPE_STRING+%7D%3B+%5C%0Apublic:+%5C%0A%09template%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E+%5C%0A%09CLASS_NAME(Args%26%26+...+args)+:+%5C%0A%09%09ErrorWithType(m_type,+std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)+%5C%0A%09%7B%7D+%5C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+the+macro+allows+creating+error+types+succinctly:+*/%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(RuntimeError,+%22Runtime+error%22)%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(LogicError,+%22Logic+error%22)%0A%0Avoid+throwError()%7B%0A%09/*+and+the+next+line+causes+the+error+*/%0A%09throw+LogicError(%22This+is+a+logic+error.%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.26568493212038,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g113,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.3+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:17.53688118466413,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.37%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.3+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:34.197433883215496,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), but not on MSVC.
The error that [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:58,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:58,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:58,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:58),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0A/*+to+get+meaningful+error+messages,+exception+classes+can+define+a+type+and%0A+*+inherit+from+ErrorWithType,+which+concatenates+the+type+and+the+passed+in%0A+*+error+message+for+what()+output+*/%0Aclass+ErrorWithType%0A%7B%0Aprotected:%0A%09std::string+m_error%3B%0A%09%0A%09std::string+errorMsg(+std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+error+)%7B%0A%09%09return+std::string%7B+typeStr+%7D+%2B+%22:+%22+%2B+error%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0Apublic:%0A%09/*+ctor+to+be+called+when+no+further+arguments+are+provided+*/%0A%09ErrorWithType(std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+error)+:%0A%09%09m_error+%7B+errorMsg(+typeStr,+std::move(error)+)+%7D%0A%09%7B%7D%0A%0A%09/*+ctor+for+chaining+to+fmt::format,+left+here+for+illustrative+purposes,%0A%09+*+but+compiler+error+occurs+elsewhere+*/%0A%09//+template%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E%0A%09//+ErrorWithType(std::string_view+typeStr,+std::string+fmtStr,+Args%26%26+...+args)+:%0A%09//+%09m_error+%7B+errorMsg(+typeStr,+fmt::format(%0A%09//+%09%09std::move(fmtStr),%0A%09//+%09%09std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)+...%0A%09//+%09)+)+%7D%0A%09//+%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09const+char*+what()+const+noexcept+%7B%0A%09%09return+m_error.c_str()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0A/*+the+error+types+are+created+with+this+macro,%0A+*+which+just+contains+a+static+string_view+member+describing+the+type,%0A+*+and+a+variadic+ctor,+which+chains+to+either+of+the+base+class+ctors.+*/%0A%23define+ERROR_WITH_TYPE(CLASS_NAME,+TYPE_STRING)+%5C%0Aclass+CLASS_NAME+:+public+ErrorWithType+%7B+%5C%0Aprivate:+static+constexpr+std::string_view+m_type+%7B+TYPE_STRING+%7D%3B+%5C%0Apublic:+%5C%0A%09template%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E+%5C%0A%09CLASS_NAME(Args%26%26+...+args)+:+%5C%0A%09%09ErrorWithType(m_type,+std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)+%5C%0A%09%7B%7D+%5C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+the+macro+allows+creating+error+types+succinctly:+*/%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(RuntimeError,+%22Runtime+error%22)%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(LogicError,+%22Logic+error%22)%0A%0Avoid+throwError()%7B%0A%09/*+and+the+next+line+causes+the+error+*/%0A%09throw+LogicError(%22This+is+a+logic+error.%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.496096481333545,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_37_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.37+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:23.08946546406811,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.37%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.37+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.41443805459836,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) throws is:

```
<source>(53): error C2665: 'ErrorWithType::ErrorWithType': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
<source>(18): note: could be 'ErrorWithType::ErrorWithType(std::string_view,std::string)'
<source>(53): note: 'ErrorWithType::ErrorWithType(std::string_view,std::string)': 
cannot convert argument 2 from 'LogicError' to 'std::string'
<source>(53): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available 
that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
<source>(53): note: while trying to match the argument list 
'(const std::string_view, LogicError)'
<source>(57): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'LogicError::LogicError<LogicError&>(LogicError &)' being compiled
```

But I don't get it.
**Why is it trying to match an argument list of '(const std::string_view, LogicError)'?** I cannot find that being represented in the code.
But that causes the spurious conversion *from* 'LogicError' *to* 'std::string', which appears to be the cause of the compiler error.

I did find a [workaround](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:22,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:22,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:22,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:22,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%22fmt/core.h%22%0A%0A%0A/*+the+error+types+are+created+with+this+macro,%0A+*+which+just+contains+a+static+string_view+member+describing+the+type,%0A+*+and+a+variadic+ctor,+which+chains+to+either+of+the+base+class+ctors.+*/%0A%23define+ERROR_WITH_TYPE(CLASS_NAME,+TYPE_STRING)+%5C%0Aclass+CLASS_NAME+:+public+std::exception+%7B+%5C%0Aprivate:+static+constexpr+std::string_view+m_type+%7B+TYPE_STRING+%7D%3B+%5C%0A%09std::string+m_error%3B+%5C%0A%09void+setError(+std::string+error+)%7B+%5C%0A%09%09m_error+%3D+std::string%7B+m_type+%7D+%2B+%22:+%22+%2B+error%3B+%5C%0A%09%7D+%5C%0Apublic:+%5C%0A++++CLASS_NAME(std::string+error)%7B+%5C%0A%09%09setError(+std::move(error)+)%3B+%5C%0A%09%7D+%5C%0A%09template%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E+%5C%0A%09CLASS_NAME(std::string+fmtStr,+Args%26%26+...+args)%7B+%5C%0A%09%09setError(+fmt::format(+%5C%0A%09%09%09std::move(fmtStr),+%5C%0A%09%09%09std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)+...+%5C%0A%09%09)+)%3B+%5C%0A%09%7D+%5C%0A%09virtual+const+char*+what()+const+noexcept+override+final+%7B+%5C%0A%09%09return+m_error.c_str()%3B+%5C%0A%09%7D+%5C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A/*+the+macro+allows+creating+error+types+succinctly:+*/%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(RuntimeError,+%22Runtime+error%22)%0AERROR_WITH_TYPE(LogicError,+%22Logic+error%22)%0A%0Avoid+throwError()%7B%0A%09/*+and+the+next+line+causes+the+error+*/%0A%09throw+LogicError(%22This+is+a+logic+error.%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.496096481333545,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_37_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:vcpkg)),options:%27/std:c%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.37+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:23.08946546406811,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.37%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.37+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.41443805459836,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), by removing the base class and putting everything into the macro, but I liked being able to minimise the amount of code in the macro - and I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: kudos for including all the relevant information in the question. Did you try to get rid of the macro? With gcc you can use the `-E` flag to see the output after preprocessing (best is to remove the includes before). Thats the code that actually triggers the error with msvc and it doesnt have the macro which just adds additional complexity: https://godbolt.org/z/3esfTasM6

Comment: I agree. The macro is the first thing everyone reading the question will have to review and remove, only to find that it fails without it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variadic constructor are dangerous, they match also (not const) copy constructor.

Adding that constructor solves the issue

```
CLASS_NAME(CLASS_NAME&) = default; \
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fPfGTPjKq)

SFINAE the constructor would be another solution.

The behavior difference should be (an allowed) (but not mandatory) copy-elision done by gcc/clang but not by msvc when [throwing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

Comment: This is a nicer workaround than what I found, but does it answer the question? Why is MSVC trying to match an argument list of '(const std::string_view, LogicError)'?

Comment: `throw LogicError("This is a logic error.")` does a copy (from non-const l-value) (elided by gcc/clang), which match your variadic constructor.

Comment: Aah, now I get it! But isn't that still covered by *guaranteed* copy elision, like in a function return? Feels like there shouldn't be two constructions, but at least now the logic makes sense, thanks!